# Soreness...DOMS?

Tags: weightlifting, beginners

Before I start off I do apologise if this is an obvious question, however I am new to this so bear with me :)

I have started getting myself back into shape lately. Yesterday I started with a 20 minute strength training workout using a pair of 5kg dumbbells consisting of:- seesaw rows, dumbbell squats, dumbbell shoulder press, calf raises, bicep curls, chest press, overhead tricep extensions & upright rows

After the workout I had some muscle weakness which is to be expected, but no soreness. I was eating right before and after the workout watching the protein intake and staying hydrated throughout.

This morning when I woke up I have soreness/stiffness in my hamstrings/backs of thighs, crease of my arms(inner elbow) and my traps?

Is this DOMS or have I injured these areas, as looking at other places there seems to be a lot of mixed information regarding this.

Thanks for reading and for any help, greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You can read about it here:http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/286/prevent-or-treat-delayed-onset-muscle-soreness?rq=1 and here: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13841/muscle-soreness?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The soreness and stiffness at the back of your legs, and the pain in your traps, likely is DOMS. It happened in about the right timeframe and it's muscles that you'd expect to be using with those exercises. Pain on the inside of the elbow is slightly more likely to be tendonitis, specifically something like Golfer's Elbow (the flipside of Tennis elbow where the pain is on the outside). You can often tell that one because it hurts considerably more when you try to straighten your arm.

The DOMS is of minor concern so long as it doesn't prevent you from being able to keep moving the next day. If it is tendonitis, that's slightly more worrying, because it can be a precursor to more permanent damage if you continue overstressing those tendons, but honestly, it's pretty common with dumbbell bicep curls when you're starting out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After looking around it does seem to be DOMS, however the elbow I'm not sure about, I had a read about golfers elbow as you mentioned and I don't really have anything other symptoms of that other than the soreness. Could that be attributed to the bicep curls as you mentioned?

Comment: It's probably not as likely because the bulk of the muscle is in the forearm or upper arm itself. The crook of the elbow is basically just where the muscle and tendons attach.

Comment: @Topher - Golfers elbow is a repetitive use injury, unlikely (although possible) that you incurred it in a single session.

Comment: @SeanDuggan I was more meaning the soreness in the crook of my elbow was caused by starting to lift weights when I am not used to it, as JohnP said Golfers Elbow is a repetitive injury, so it seems unlikely that it is golfers elbow considering yesterday was the first time I have lifted weights. Thanks for the info and replies :)

Comment: That's fair. I do still think it's more likely tendons than muscles in that case. It has been linked to bicep curls.